# jquery insert a html block so it starts before the target and ends after the target - is this possible?

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I understand you can add insert blocks of html before and after a target using `before()`, `insertBefore()`, `after()` and `insertAfter()`.

I tried to do something similar to this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("p").before("<div class='myContainer'>");
        $("p").after("</div>");
    });
</script>

<p>paragraph</p>
```

But the inject seems to automatically create closing tags for me, is there a way around this?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a function for that :)  Use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), like this:

```
$("p").wrap("<div class='myContainer'>");
```

This will wrap each `<p>` independent, [you can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3P3je/), it changes this:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>​
```

Into this:

```
<div class='myContainer'>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
</div>
<div class='myContainer'>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>​
</div>
```

Comment: "There's a function for that".. nice slogan for jQuery :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, and yes nice slogan hehe

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention you could also do:

```
$myDiv = $("<div class='myContainer'></div>");
$("p").wrap($myDiv);
```

and then again at a later time append stuff to myDiv with

```
$myDiv.append("This is going to be the text in myContainer");
```

Comment: He wants to wrap the `<div>` around the `<p>` though, this would result in `<p>Something</p><div class='myContainer'></div>`.